# \tableofcontents and multiple files from \include

Tags: table-of-contents, include, revtex

I am trying to compile a table of contents with `\tableofcontents{}` from multiple files I have included (with `\include`, i.e. chapters).

What do I need to do to get the chapters included in the table of contents?

It would appear that the sections from the files do not register themselves into the `*.toc` file. However, I have no idea why.

This is the root document I have:

```
\documentclass[english,aps]{revtex4}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}

\title{This is the title}
\maketitle

\tableofcontents{} %oops :-)

\input{includes/chapters/0_preliminaries}
\include{includes/chapters/x_appendix}

\end{document}
```

And this is one of the leaf(?) documents (i.e. 0_preliminaries):

```
\section{Preliminaries}
Text goes here
```

So, The problem is that with the `\input{*}` the file is included in the `*.toc`, while with the `\include{*}` it is not.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Normally all `\chapter`s and other sectioning commands should appear in the ToC (up to the selected level). Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem. You might do something wrong.

Comment: ok, will do. Thanks for the quick reaction ;-)

Answer (score 5):

The documentclass `revtex4` doesn't provide the using of `\include`.

You can open the `aux`-file of `x_appendix` and you will find the command `\@setckpt` which is defined as `\def\@setckpt#1#2{}`.

You should change the document class.